# iphone:searchbar remove background when interface changes

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisearchbar

I have used this code to remove background behind searchbar but when I rotate the view to Landscape or launch the application in landscape view a black container is displayed around searchbar

```
for (UIView *searchSubview in mySearchBar.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"Subview: %@", searchSubview);
    if ([searchSubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        //[searchSubview removeFromSuperview];
        [searchSubview setAlpha:0.0];
        //[searchSubview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        //break;
    }
}
```

Please enlighten me on this. I tried to implement this code in willRotate, shouldRotate and didRotate methods but problem persist. Please enlighten me on this.

Regards
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it ....

open the interface builder
under searchbar attributes in view,  Mode is set as 'Redraw' set it to scaleToFill